# How can I allow normal users to mount tmpfs under subdirectories of their home directory?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, mount, tmpfs

How can I allow normal users to mount a tmpfs under any subdirectory owned by them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably have to write a wrapper script that you would allow them to execute with sudo.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking about giving them partial sudo rights to mount and umount.

First add user nisse to the group users

```
addgroup nisse users
```

Then allow the group users to execute mount and umount, add this in /etc/sudoers

```
%users  ALL=(ALL) /bin/mount
%users  ALL=(ALL) /bin/umount
```

Then the user should be allowed to mount a tmpfs drive.

And if you follow Jayen answer with a wrapper scipt, then add something like this to sudoers

```
%users  ALL=(ALL) /usr/local/bin/mount_tmpfs.sh
```

If that wrapper script is called /usr/local/bin/mount_tmpfs.sh

/Good luck

Comment: Obviously, giving access to `mount` without restrictions is a huge security risk and almost equivalent to giving them root access.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make a wrapper binary that is suid root (but that is more effort.)